# Best way to invite collaborators in a modal?

Tags: desktop-application, modal

**Background**

We have a modal (with overlay) that displays a full list of collaborators in a folder (desktop app). It's possible to change permission or remove a collaborator, and search to streamline the list. Header (with search) and modal footer are fixed, and content is scrollable.

[image: Modal wireframe with header, search bar, and list of collaborators stacked vertically.]

**Idea**

I'm trying to scale this modal to an instance when user searches for a collaborator (entry point), but they're not in the list. In this case, how user can invite a new collaborator? It should be easy to do so without navigating to another modal page.

**Option**

Once user searches for a collaborator, instead of displaying a list of collaborators, I was thinking of displaying all users in the database/enterprise (whether they're a collaborator or not). List could display collaborators first, and the rest.

With a short indicator, it could be easy to inform user this collaborator item is different and not invited yet. By selecting a permission (same component as selected permission, but empty state) the "Invite" button would be active.

[image]

**Doubts**

I'm struggling finding the best indicator (whether inline notice or a banner outside of modal) to inform when a search result is not a collaborator yet. Would it also make sense to validate these changes after pressing "Save" in modal footer? Do you have any examples with similar workflow? I appreciate any thoughts and feedback, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the site! My design would have contained a "Add" button to explicitly trigger adding a new collaborator. Your design circumvents this by searching and showing collaborators and non-collaborators together - nice! What I do not understand is what you are worried about: The design provides a clear indication (the "Invite" button) what needs to be done next. Which changes do you think about validating?